# Сколько всего желательно иметь таблиц в базе данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, дублирование

Есть база данных состоящая из 5 таблиц. В одной храниться порядка 10+ млн записей. Количество записей, кот. нужно еще заполнить, порядка 120-150 млн. Где каждая новая запись записывается на опр. время дольше, чем предыдущая, т.к. идет проверка на дубликаты.

И поэтому у меня два пути, оставить как есть и ждать пару недель на сохранения инфы. Или же создать, условно говоря пару тысяч таблиц, для мобильности самой бд, т.к. там используются порядка 2-х тысяч разных типов инфы.

И вот для каждого типа инфы, будет использоваться своя таблица. Но не уверен, правильное ли решение.

Как поступить? Может есть третье, четвертое и т.д. решение.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под _типами инфы_. Очевидно, если рецепт кексов  вы будете записывать в одну таблицу с характеристиками смартфона, создав для них общий перечень полей. то это не лучшее решение.

Comment: Информация которая храниться в таблице, это цены на определенные товары, а тип информации, это условно говоря, марка телефона, таких марок около 2-х тысяч

Answer (score 5):

Если вы можете сразу определить тип инфы с помощью безнес логики то лучше обращаться непосредственно к той таблице у которой этот тип инфы определен. Маленький размер таблицы удобнее использовать. Но если бизнес логика хромает, то время затраченное на поиск нужного типа инфы не окупается по сравнению с индексным поиском этого типа инфы в таблице.

Comment: Вся таблица выглядит примерно так (максимально упрощенный вариант), `id`, `type`, `price`, `date`, где типов порядка 2-х тыс. Поиск же происходит по типу и по времени. А тип записи изначально известен, и я подумал, что если оставить эту структуру дальше такой же, как сейчас, то времени на проверку уходит на порядок больше, чем если создать для каждого типа свою таблицу. Скорость увеличилась более чем в 7 раз. Но вот выглядит это все не эстетично. И думаю, что это не то решение, кот. должно быть.

Comment: Если вы можете оптимизировать запросы, то это может улучшить время на проверку, но не зная броду не лезь в воду как говорится.

Answer (score 3):

> Есть база данных состоящая из 5 таблиц. В одной храниться порядка 10+ млн записей. Количество записей, кот. нужно еще заполнить, порядка 120-150 млн. Где каждая новая запись записывается на опр. время дольше, чем предыдущая, т.к. идет проверка на дубликаты.

Если я верно понимаю, то речь идёт о процессе заполнения имеющейся структуры имеющимися данными, и хочется ускорить этот процесс.

В таком случае настоятельно рекомендую выполнить импорт данных во временную структуру без проведения каких-либо проверок (Для MySQL импорт 150кк записей такой простой структуры с применением LOAD DATA INFILE выполняется достаточно быстро), затем выполнить средствами SQL требуемые проверки с удалением дубликатов (и предварительно - необходимые индексирования для быстрого выполнения этих операций), и, наконец, перенос заведомо корректных очищенных данных в боевую таблицу. Для указанных количества и структуры цена вопроса - порядка 3-4 часов.

> для каждого типа инфы, будет использоваться своя таблица

А вот тут - полная неясность. Но с учётом того, что

> тип информации, это условно говоря, марка телефона, таких марок около 2-х тысяч

скорее всего речь ведётся о простом словаре - тогда вполне достаточно к основной таблице цен иметь ещё одну таблицу с типами телефонов. Но уж никак не две тысячи...

Comment: Не все так однозначно. Есть куча файлов (на данный момент их более 83к шт), с определенной структурой (строка разделенная по пробелу, где каждая новая строка - новый sql запрос). И содержимое файлов (цены на товары аукциона) нужно перенести в бд. Но просто копирование содержимого файлов, не вариант, т.к. в нужно будет выводить на страницу все цены для опред. типа товара. В общем делать ряд сортировок, уже после сохранения инфы.

Comment: *каждая новая строка - новый sql запрос* Непонятная фраза. Добавьте в свой вопрос пример (2-3 строки) данных из такого файла. *копирование содержимого файлов, не вариант, т.к. в нужно будет выводить на страницу* Вы ещё данные в таблицы не занесли - так что думать об их выводе куда-то, мягко говоря, рановато.